# Get the amount of time user was logged in an application

Tags: php

**How can I measure the amount of time a user was logged into my web application (php)?**

I implemented a solution which relies on storing in a database the login timestamp and the logout timestamp (*logout = when the user clicks a logout button*), but problems occur if the user forgets to log out and just closes the application.

Any better approach?

Many thanks!

Comment: What are you using for login, Cookies or Sessions?

Comment: Well, What i can think of is, you can send an ajax call when user closes browser and manually update timestamp. You can use `$( window ).unload()` to trigger the ajax call.

Comment: Not a whole solution, but you could always generate a "last activity" timestamp (whenever a user opens up a page) and use this whenever logout wasn't triggered. Maybe also consider something like https://moodle.org/mod/data/view.php?d=13&rid=4200 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can periodically ping the server from the client. Counting those pings for the user gives you the idea when a user's browser window is still opened. It doesn't mean the user is actively interacting with the application, but it answers your question.

Prepare a server-side endpoint to receive the ping call. Then start a periodic js function on the page to do the ping when the page loads:

```
setInterval(function () { callPingEndpoint(); }, 1000 * seconds);
```